# how to get remaining time of agent in delay block in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have three agents in delay block and i want to get remaining time of the agent which have maximum remaining time left at particular state/interval, i want to use getremainingtime() method but i dont know how to use it if delay block contains more than one agent. Further details and names can be seen in attached picture. [image: please refer to this image].

i am expecting remaingtime of single agent from delay block whereas delay block contains multiple agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the agent with the max remaining time in the delay by using the following code snippet

```
double maxRemainingTime = 0;
Agent maxRemainingAgent = null;
for(int i = 0; i < delay.size(); i ++){
    if (delay.getRemainingTime(delay.get(i)) > maxRemainingTime) {
        maxRemainingAgent = delay.get(i);
        maxRemainingTime = delay.getRemainingTime(maxRemainingAgent);
    }
}
```

Or if you know a thing or two about streams and you only want the max time value and not the agent, you can get everything in a single line of code

`double x = findAll(delay, e -> true).stream().mapToDouble(e -> delay.getRemainingTime(e)).max().orElse(0);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is a great help, i have also cracked the solution using ArrayList and solution looks like this. 
int i =0;
for(Agent elements:delay){
list.add(i,delay.getRemainingTime(elements));
i++;
}
maxValue=Collections.max(list);

Comment: That is great! Glad my answer helped. Rember to accept it, and upvote if you think it worthy ;-) 
My solution helps you find the agent that has the max waiting time as well. 
I wanted to use a streams, which is even simpler. See my updated answer